# Counting the number of parenthesization

Tags: dynamic-programming, matrices

I'm reading CLRS and there is something I don't understand regarding counting the number of parenthesization, in the Matrix-chain multiplication chapter, the book says:

> Denote the number of alternative parenthesizations of a sequence of $n$ matrices by $P(n)$. When $n$ = 1, we have just one matrix and therefore only one way to fully parenthesize the matrix product. When $n$ $\geq$ 2, a fully parenthesized matrix product is the product of two fully parenthesized matrix subproducts, and the split between the two subproducts may occur between the $k$th and ($k$ + 1)st matrices for any $k$ = 1, 2, ..., $n$ - 1.

what I don't understand is the the part about the split? what exactly does it mean to split the two subproducts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The split in a product is between the two outermost pairs of parantheses. For example, in $((a*b)*(c*d))*(e*f)$, the split is between the $d$ and $e$ because the last multiplication that is performed is between the results of the products $abcd$ and $ef$.  The split tells you where the last multiplication is performed and let’s you decompose the problem into two subproblems.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have $n$ matrices $M_1, M_2, …, M_n$.

The product of all matrices is $M_1\times M_2\times…\times M_n$ and since the matrix product is associative, there is no need for parentheses from a mathematical point of view.

However, from a complexity perspective, the product may not takes the same amount of computation time if you compute $M_1\times (M_2\times … \times M_n)$ or $(M_1\times M_2)\times (M_3\times…\times M_n)$ and so on.

For example, using the naive matrix multiplication algorithm, if $n = 3$ and the dimensions of $M_1$ are $10 \times 100$, the dimensions of $M_2$ are $100\times 5$ and the dimensions of $M_3$ are $5\times 2$, then computing $M_1\times (M_2\times M_3)$ uses $100\times 5 \times 2 + 10 \times 100 \times 2 = 3000$ scalar multiplications, but computing $(M_1\times M_2)\times M_3$ uses $10\times 100 \times 5 + 10 \times 5 \times 2 = 5100$ scalar multiplications.

The split the book is talking about is about the position of the parentheses in the computation, separating the computation of $n$ matrices into the product of two matrices, the first one being the result of $M_1\times … \times M_k$ and the second one of $M_{k+1}\times …\times M_n$, for a certain $k\in \{1, …, n-1\}$.

Comment: I understand, thank you.